# Outlook: How to show recipient email address in column?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In order to show the FROM email-address in Outlook (2016) instead of the name only, I created a new formula based column*:

right([SearchFromEmail],len([SearchFromEmail])-InStr(1,[SearchFromEmail],"@"))

It works fine except that allegedly (see answer below) formula based columns cannot be sorted.

However, I still do not know how to do the same for the TO email address. When I replace in the above formula the "From" with "To", Outlook says 'unknown field'.

The 'To' information is right there in the internet header follwing 'From' and it should be possible to extract it with a formula the same way. Only how?

Exporting the fields to Excel works fine, which is a workaround but a little inconvenient. On the plus side, the columns can be sorted.

---

*Source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2190-outlook-view-sender-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

> > The formula works but the column says it "can not be sorted by this field". Why?

According the reply of MVP in [this similar thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sorting-formula-user-defined-fields/9555cbbd-233a-4200-a1aa-6b42ae2e0ca3), "formula" and "combination" type fields exist only at the "folder" level and cannot be sorted or grouped via the Outlook UI.

> > If I change in the formula the "From" to "To" in order to show the recipient e-mail address in another column as well, Outlook 2010 says 'unknown field'.

This cannot be realized. No such a "formula" to show recipient’s domain.

I found that we can use macro to relace email address with names. You may see if [this link](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/replace-display-names-email-addresses/) works for you.

Comment: Thanks, the macro solution seems to be for a slightly different purpose. It drops the name and shows the address when you create a message.